# Remove from list with iterator, start from second value

Tags: java

I have list of Strings, and I wonder how it is possible.

my list:

```
>         listOfStrings.add("first");
>         listOfStrings.add("second");
>         listOfStrings.add("third");
```

my method

```
public List<String> removeStringFromList(String enteredString) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<String> iter = listOfStrings.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String abc = iter.next();
        if (abc.equals(enteredString)){
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

this line:

> String abc = iter.next();

says, abc is next value in my list, so this loop starting from second value.

So how it possible, when I put "first" to this method, this method will remove "first" element in list ?

Comment: "says, abc is next value in my list, so this loop starting from second value."  No.  The iterator starts before the beginning of the list, so the first call to `next` returns the first element.

Comment: Note that your whole code could be replaced by `listOfStrings.removeIf(e -> e.equals(enteredString))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterator will start from the first element. In this particular case, since you want to skip the first element, you can do so by simply by changing this:

```
Iterator<String> iter = listOfStrings.iterator();
```

to this:

```
Iterator<String> iter = listOfStrings.subList(1,listOfStrings.size()).iterator();
```

This utilizes the `subList` method to return a view of the portion of the `listOfStrings` list between the specified `1`, inclusive, and `listOfStrings.size()`, exclusive.

---

You can also use streams to accomplish the desired result like so:

```
List<String> result =
        IntStream.range(1, listOfStrings.size())
                 .filter(index -> !listOfStrings.get(index).equals(enteredString))
                 .mapToObj(listOfStrings::get)
                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```